# patient_count based on cancer occurrence column

Tags: sql, rdbms

I need a patient count for the condition based on the cancer occurrence. I'll share the sample dataset and the expected result for your reference.

```
ID  Date        Inf Cancer
123 05/05/2000  1   0
123 08/07/2001  0   1
123 06/07/2002  1   0
159 01/03/2001  1   1
159 02/08/2002  0   1
618 07/07/2005  0   0
618 05/03/2006  1   0
789 06/06/2000  1   0
789 04/02/2001  0   1
789 03/03/2002  1   0
```

I have 2 conditions to get the count of patients.

1. Patients who are Infected(Inf=1) after/same date on cancer (cancer=1)  Expected Output(IDs 123,159,789).
2. Patients who are Infected(Inf=1) before cancer (cancer=1) Expected Output(IDs 123,789).

Kindly suggests a code to get the patient IDs list at the end of the result.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables. can you please also add the expected output?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: can you please give as sample data and show us expected data ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists` to get the patients.  For instance, for the first condition:

```
select distinct t.id
from t
where t.inf = 1 and
      exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.id = t.id and
                    t2.cancer = 1 and
                    t2.date <= t.date
             );
```

You can do something similar for the second condition as well.